# Skip a behave step based on parameter

Tags: python, python-behave

I want to skip test based on parameter:

```
Scenario Outline: something
  Examples:
    | param |
    | true  |
    | false |
  ...
  Then check something if <param>
    | there | can     | be   |
    | some  | context | data |
```

So if `param` is `true`, we do this step. If not - not.

How to implement it? `check something` can be any step.

I tried the following:

```py
@then('{optional_step} if "{valid_param}"')
def step(context, optional_step: str, valid_param: Any = True):
    if not valid_param or not bool(valid_param) or int(valid_param) == 0:
        return
    context.execute_steps(f'Then {optional_step}')
```

But the problem is that table under the step name is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with some hacky solution:

```py
@given('{optional_step} if "{valid_param}"')
def step(context, optional_step: str, valid_param: Any = True):
    _optional_step('Given', context, optional_step, valid_param)


@when('{optional_step} if "{valid_param}"')
def step(context, optional_step: str, valid_param: Any = True):
    _optional_step('When', context, optional_step, valid_param)


@then('{optional_step} if "{valid_param}"')
def step(context, optional_step: str, valid_param: Any = True):
    _optional_step('Then', context, optional_step, valid_param)


def _optional_step(step_type, context, optional_step: str, valid_param: Any = True):
    if not valid_param or not bool(valid_param) or int(valid_param) == 0:
        return
    new_step = [f'{step_type} {optional_step}']
    if context.table:
        new_step.append(str(context.table))
    if context.text:
        new_step.append(f'"""\n{str(context.text)}\n"""')
    replaced_step = '\n'.join(new_step) + '\n'
    context.execute_steps(replaced_step)
```